# Hide show div, starting in Show mode

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I'm using a show/hide javascript code.

You can find an example here http://ledonnedelre.com/test.htm

Basically if you click the ? on the top left, an help box appears. And after you can close it clicking again the button.

What i need is to have the help box already opened when you open the page.

I guess i should change something in this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                            //change the button label to be 'Show'
            toggle_switch.html('?');
          }else{
                            //change the button label to be 'Hide'
            toggle_switch.html('NASCONDI');
          }
        });
      });

    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CSS issue. Set

```
display: block;
```

on the hidden element.

Comment: @HenryStrife: the element is called '#collapse1', by the way!

Comment: i added it to the page, but it's not showing up the help box when you enter the page... what's wrong? :)  http://ledonnedelre.com/test.htm

Comment: so...what should i add to the css? :))) Thank you for your help!! :)

Comment: There are some CSS rules inline on the `#collapse1` element: `<div id="collapse1" style="display:none ; z-index: 1000; background-color: #DDDDDD ">`. As you can see, the element is being hidden by the `display: none` setting!

Comment: Genius!! It's working! Just, it's a bit "annoying" that it doesnt appear the right text, that should be "nascondi" (hide)

Comment: @HenryStrife: You can change that, too: just replace the `?` with the correct text in the HTML. Your Javascript toggle function will handle changing it appropriately.

Comment: @HenryStrife: No problem! :) If you just accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, that's more than enough.